# How to create/ vectorize/ digitize a hand drawn logo and retain its look?

Tags: vector, logo, sketch-app

I just receive my first "official" drawing/logo project and I'm not sure how to get about doing it.

So this client asked me for a drawing for a brand logo that he's planning on doing (just a drawing for now, but maybe a logo later on, but I'll need to tell him my rates and all). So I'm planning to tell him that I don't do drawings but I do provide logo designs. But if he wants a hand drawn logo, how can I go about doing that?

I know that obviously I can't just scan it since it won't be resizeable. But turning it into a vector would be either too clean or too jaggy (lol, is that even a word). I'm curious if any. How would you go about doing it?

PS: If there are other questions/thread available already on the site, pls do let me know. Sry if it's a duplicate.

Comment: Do you guys use textured brushes?

Comment: This question is all over the place. The question asks how to vectorize a hand-drawn logo. But the body says you don't do drawings. Yet you are taking on a "drawing/logo" project.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to an iPhone or iPad, you could try using [Adobe Shape](http://www.adobe.com/products/shape.html). It uses the device camera to take pictures and convert the pictures into vectors.

Comment: But cant Android users use it too using an iOS emulator?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the look you want on the logo. If it's very sketchy, or has something like watercolor textures it might be harder to vectorize, but it is possible to achieve a hand-drawn look  in all vector using illustrator brushes and textures.

It is also possible to have a hand-drawn version (that you maybe draw big and scan at a high resolution so you have a file that can be used a lot)and a simplified vector version that you can use for when the bitmap version is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

If the logo will be used for commercial purposes then it must be professionally vectorized. Don't even think about automated vector conversion tools. They are providing terrible vector images that can not be used for any company. Check blue link with tutorial that will show you how to vectorize company logo with a pen tool in adobe illustrator - 
[How to turn pixel image into vector](http://vectorizeimages.blogspot.sk/2015/01/how-to-turn-pixel-image-into-vector.html)

Comment: That link shows you how to use an automated vector conversion tool, not the Pen tool...